# Outlook 2016: "The set of folders cannot be opened. the information store could not be opened" after connection loss

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange-2010, microsoft-outlook-2016

This error *has* been addressed here before, but none of the answers provided have worked in our environment.

Some background: Our users are all using Windows 7 enterprise with Office 365 running 2016. Our mailboxes are all stored onsite and users are unable to run exchange in cached mode - there's no PST or OST to repair.

None of them have Admin access to their workstations, but this has been an ongoing issue since we were using outlook 2010, when all of them had admin access to their workstation.

Occasionally when outlook disconnects from the network it fails to reconnect, and when they try to open it again they get the error:

> Cannot start Microsoft Outlook. Cannot open the Outlook Window. The set of folders cannot be opened. The information store could not be opened.

We've definitely tried these fixes: Running outlook in safe mode, running outlook with the resetnavpane switch, running the inbox repair tool (which we can't actually use), making a new mail profile, or turning off compatibility mode.

The only thing that fixes this for our users 100% of the time is running a quick repair of office. Sometimes restarting the computer works as well.

Most of our users are fine, but anyone working over VPN, or using a floating workstation (laptop, tablet) tends to run into this pretty often.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this issue that I haven't mentioned here? repairing works, but it would be a tough pill for our users to swallow.

**Edit for anyone finding this in the future:** We were never able to find a solution, but we DID find a much faster workaround. Closing all MS office apps and then opening outlook fixes it, at least for that session, every time in my experience. As far as I can tell the error is getting "stuck" in office, and the reason a repair worked in the past is that it would close every other office process, rather than anything the repair was doing mechanically.

I hope this helps! It's easier to direct our users to close out of skype and try again than to try to run a quick repair from the software center.